# Socket IO runOnUiThread doesn't work

Tags: android, socket.io, android-runonuithread

I have trouble with runOnUiThread in socket io. I use this [library](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java). I have listener for some event. If I get this event I change the image. But when I get event image stay as before and I don't understand why it's happen. Maybe someone help or explain me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance. This is my code

```
private void online(){
    SocketService.getSocket().on("online", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("myLogs", "online");
                    onlineOffline.setImageResource(R.drawable.online);
                    callTo.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                    callToRegion.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void offline() {
    SocketService.getSocket().on("offline", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("myLogs", "offline");
                    onlineOffline.setImageResource(R.drawable.offline);
                    callTo.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                    callToRegion.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT!

Socket connected successfully and I can see message online/offline in the log. Also I debug code and don't show error. Full code

```
public class ProfileList extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

private int pos=0;
private DecodeBitmap decodeBitmap=new DecodeBitmap();
private ArrayList<String> online = new ArrayList<>();
private ImageView onlineOffline;
private RelativeLayout callToRegion;
private Button callTo;
private Activity activity;

static ProfileList newInstance(int position, ArrayList<String> online) {
    ProfileList pageFragment = new ProfileList();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt("page", position);
    arguments.putStringArrayList("online", online);
    pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return pageFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pos = getArguments().getInt("page");
    online = getArguments().getStringArrayList("online");
    Log.d("myLogs", "page pos: " + pos);
    activity = getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list_layout, container, false);
    Log.d("myLogs","fragment onCreateView pos "+ pos);
    callToRegion = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.callToRegion);
    callTo = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.callTo);
    ImageView mainProfileIcon = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainProfileIcon);
    onlineOffline = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.onlineOffline);
    if(CallPageFragment.online.get(0).equals("empty")){
        new LoadDataFromDatabase("relatives", getActivity(), "");
    }
    if(LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.size()==0){
        DialogFragment dlgFragment = new ErrorPopupFragment();
        int REQUEST_CODE_DIALOG = 101;
        dlgFragment.setTargetFragment(this, REQUEST_CODE_DIALOG);
        dlgFragment.setCancelable(true);
        String dialogTitle = "error_dialog";
        dlgFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), dialogTitle);
        activity.onBackPressed();
    }
    else {
        callTo.setText(LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getFirstName());
        File imgFile = new File(LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getAvatar());
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            mainProfileIcon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            mainProfileIcon.setImageBitmap(decodeBitmap.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getAvatar(), 300, 300));
        }
    }
    Log.d("myLogs", "all relatives online" + online);
    Log.d("myLogs", "all relatives" + LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getRelativesId());
    if(online.size()==0){
        onlineOffline.setImageResource(R.drawable.offline);
        Log.d("myLogs", "online false");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("myLogs", "online true " + pos + " " + LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getRelativesId());
        for(int i=0;i<online.size();i++) {
            if (LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getRelativesId().equals(online.get(i))) {
                Log.d("myLogs", "online id " + LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getRelativesId() + " " + online.get(i) + " pos: " + pos);
                onlineOffline.setImageResource(R.drawable.online);
                callTo.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                callToRegion.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                break;
            }
            else {
                onlineOffline.setImageResource(R.drawable.offline);
                callTo.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        MainActivity.textClock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    catch(Throwable e) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "WTF???!!!!", e);
    }
    online();
    offline();
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    CallPageFragment.currentPosition=pos;
    Log.d("myLogs","save currentPosition " + CallPageFragment.currentPosition);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("firstName", LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getFirstName());
    bundle.putString("avatar", LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getAvatar());
    bundle.putString("id", LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getRelativesId());
    Fragment fragment = new CallToFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
}

private void online(){
    SocketService.getSocket().on("online", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("myLogs", "online");
                    onlineOffline.setImageResource(R.drawable.online);
                    callTo.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                    callToRegion.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void offline() {
    SocketService.getSocket().on("offline", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("myLogs", "offline");
                    onlineOffline.setImageResource(R.drawable.offline);
                    callTo.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                    callToRegion.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SocketService.getSocket().off("online");
    SocketService.getSocket().off("offline");
}
```

}

Comment: You should post your SocketService implementation, as well as the rest of the code where you are using those methods.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already solved my issue. I dont know why, but runOnUiThread works fine. I three days tried to find whats wrong with my code and than it have just work. It's fully working code

```
private void online(){
    if (SocketService.getSocket() != null)
        SocketService.getSocket().on("online", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.d("myLogs", "online");
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("myLogs", "online");
                        onlineOffline.setImageResource(R.drawable.online);
                        callToRegion.setOnClickListener(ProfileList.this);
                        tvHelpDescription.setText("To call " + LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getFirstName() + " " +
                                LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getLastName() + " tap here");
                        CallPageFragment.arrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    else{
        Log.e("myLogs", "Socket is null");
    }
}

private void offline() {
    if(SocketService.getSocket() != null) {
        SocketService.getSocket().on("offline", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("myLogs", "offline");
                        onlineOffline.setImageResource(R.drawable.offline);
                        callToRegion.setOnClickListener(null);
                        tvHelpDescription.setText("You can't call " + LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getFirstName() + " " +
                                LoadDataFromDatabase.relativesData.get(pos).getLastName() + " because she offline");
                        CallPageFragment.arrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        Log.e("myLogs", "Socket is null");
    }
}
```